# Eclipse WST server "Automatically publish when resources change" doesn't publish on file change

Tags: eclipse, server

I have a WST server implementation where I have defined already a `ServerDelegate`, `ServerBehaviourDelegate` & `ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate` for my specific server type. Being short, basic functionality works fine. However I want to implement the "Automatically publish when resources change" option located on the server editor. When I select this, I don't see the `publish` method being called when a file of a Module added to the server has changed, I did some research and overrided the `getListenerPaths` from the `ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate` child class, but besides this I'm not sure what can I be missing.

Comment: Are automatic builds enabled?

Comment: No, but I would expect that for specific build events the option to be in charge of this is the one that says "Automatically publish after a build event"